# Failed to start containerd: timeout waiting for containerd to start in dockerd-rootless.sh

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-18.04

System is Ubuntu 18.04.
Docker Version:19.03.8
After trying to setup to run docker in rootless mode as explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) I can not do this, and I encounter error after running command `dockerd-rootless.sh --experimental` :

```
INFO[2020-04-25T15:35:33.721952447+02:00] Starting up                                  
WARN[2020-04-25T15:35:33.722001718+02:00] Running experimental build                   
WARN[2020-04-25T15:35:33.722008008+02:00] Running in rootless mode. Cgroups, AppArmor, and CRIU are disabled. 
INFO[2020-04-25T15:35:33.722012842+02:00] Running with RootlessKit integration         
INFO[2020-04-25T15:35:33.722794485+02:00] libcontainerd: containerd is still running    pid=6091
INFO[2020-04-25T15:35:33.722825212+02:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-25T15:35:33.722887823+02:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-25T15:35:33.722902875+02:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/user/1000/docker/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2020-04-25T15:35:33.722917631+02:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
failed to start containerd: timeout waiting for containerd to start
[rootlesskit:child ] error: command [/home/vasko/bin/dockerd-rootless.sh --experimental] exited: exit status 1
[rootlesskit:parent] error: child exited: exit status 1
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: @MMM Whats wrong, how can I make it work?